# docker container: add symlink to /Users/www/[project] in /var/www to access and serve local files

Tags: docker, coldfusion, lucee

I am trying to serve local CFML files on my mac via the Lucee docker container (https://hub.docker.com/r/lucee/lucee5/).
I got so far as to mount the specific folder on my mac to a symlink within my docker images

`docker run -it imagename -v /Users/[username]/www/projectx:/code /bin/bash`

So on the bash in the docker image I now have /code.
I then create a symlink `ln -s /code projectx` in my `/var/www`.

When I then serve the image running tomcat whilst also mounting the the folder

`docker run -p 1337:8888 -v /Users/[username]/www/projectx:/code [imagename] catalina.sh run`

I would expect to be able to access `http://localhost:1337/projectx`
Unfortunately it can't find that folder. Probably since Lucee doesn't recognises or indexes the the files on run time?

Is this possible?

The outcome I am look at is developing my Coldfusion app on my MAC while running Lucee+mysql on my docker container and having the source code locally so that I don't have to play with samba shares or other ways to be able to edit the coldfusion files in my IDE. (Samba share stopped working when I upgraded to Sierra)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered simply mounting the code directory onto `/var/www`, which is the default VOLUME mount point in the Lucee Docker image?  If you really want it to be in a /code subdirectory, then have that subdirectory on your host instead of playing with symlinks.

An easy way to do this is using docker-compose, for example the following `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '2'

services:
  web:
    image: lucee/lucee5
    ports:
      - "1337:8888"
    volumes:
      - /Users/[username]/www/projectx:/var/www
```

You can then run this by using `docker-compose up`

Comment: Yeah, this seems to work. Brilliant, that is so much more simple. The only thing I need to correct now is that in my /projectx folder I have 4 websites:
So /projectx/player/root (which has the index.cfm) and /projectx/custmer/root (which has the index.cfm etc.. On my webserver each of those is a separate apache2 website where the root is folder is what is configured in apache. Since I access for example http://localhost:1337/customer/root/ it will require separate configured websites. My head is a bit foggy after a nap so I am not sure how to tackle this right now

Comment: Why not just install apache and have it mirror your production environment?  I've done just that, installing apache over the top of the lucee5 image

Comment: I tried altering the lucee5 image but then I get and exit code 0 when I try to run it. Not really sure where I can find the logging or what is going wrong. But yes, apache would be a good addition so that I can set up the multiple website and make each website virtualhost look at the volume coming from my Mac

Comment: Whilst I will happily help with modifying the Lucee image, it's not really what you were asking in this question Please put together a new question with what you have tried so far relating to that, and if one of the solutions on this question answered this question then accept it - else this will become unuseful for people in the future.

Comment: I created a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41646946/customize-lucee5-docker-image-to-allow-running-of-multiple-website-within-the-im

Answer (score 0):

Unless there is a need to have the content of `/code` change during the lifetime of the container, you can just COPY or ADD it during the container build. 
if not, as Simon suggested above, it makes more sense to mount the volume directly where you want to use it. make it RO if you don't want the container to change anything in the volume.

Comment: No real need, I am quiet new at using docker myself so I am not exactly sure what is possible. I just want to run my project with 4 subsites which is sitting in the folder and it can run directly on /var/www. I just have to figure out how I can run 4 different websites on that docker service. Maybe configure apache or tomcat to host them? I used to run a virtual linux machine on ma mac that would have mysql and apache on it and then have  samba share so I could edit the code while running it on my virtual box image. Since osx Sierra I can can't connect anymore. Hence my docker attempt

Comment: it sounds more like an issue of Apache, not Docker.
so, running multiple 'sites' by the same server is called virtual-hosts in Apache (if I remember correctly), and if that's what your looking for, I would advise first to install Apache on your computer, configuring it without Docker and then moving it into a container.
on the other hand, if you are looking to run 4 containers, each serving one 'site', it is a matter of building a containerized server, and then running it with 4 different content folders.