# customize lucee5 docker image to allow running of multiple website within the image

Tags: docker-compose, lucee

I am running the lucee5 image with docker-compose and that works well. I was able to link my local volume into the dockerimages.
the local project contains 4 websites which should all run within the docker image.
I would like to be able to connect to them like localhost:1337/customer and localhost:1337/player and localhost:1337/etc..

So for this I have to setup Apache on the docker image which I know how to do. However, when I quit stop docker-compose and try to persist the last container with the new changes, I run into a error message when I want to run that new container using compose (exit code 0).

My end goals is to be able to start up docker-compose so that I have my 3 websites available for testing and I can work on the project locally in my IDE whilst docker is running that same source.
I know I could put my MYSQL database also outside of the docker-image and reference it.

How do I tackle that error exit 0 when changing my image?

My Docker Compose file

```
version: '2'

services:
  web:
  image: lucee/lucee5
  ports:
  - "1337:8888"
volumes:
  - /Users/matti/www/projectx/:/var/www/
```

projectx has 3 subfolders which have 3 cfml roots that run the index.cfm:

```
projectx/customer/root -> index.cfm
projectx/play/root -> index.cfm
projectx/tracker/root -> index.cfm
```

I would make 3 apache websites in apache on the lucee5 image.

Comment: Please provide your Dockerfile.  Additionally you can use docker-compose  to manage a stack easily - once I see your Dockerfile I can advise changes to make it a bit simpler.  Docker is best used with containers for each task.

Comment: I have updated the story as requested

Answer (score 3):

The easiest method to run 3 apps using the Lucee docker image would be to define a service for each in your docker compose file, e.g.

```
version: '2'

services:
  customer-app:
    image: lucee/lucee5
    ports:
      - "8001:8888"
    volumes:
      - /your/path/to/projectx/customer/root:/var/www
      # the line below is an example of how to customise the lucee-web.xml.cfm for this app
      - /your/path/to/projectx/customer/lucee/lucee-web.xml.cfm:/opt/lucee/web/lucee-web.xml.cfm
  play-app:
    image: lucee/lucee5
    ports:
      - "8002:8888"
    volumes:
      - /your/path/to/projectx/play/root:/var/www
  tracker-app:
    image: lucee/lucee5
    ports:
      - "8003:8888"
    volumes:
      - /your/path/to/projectx/tracker/root:/var/www
```

If you need to access each app via a single hostname but different URL paths (i.e. mydomain.local/customer, mydomain.local/play, mydomain.local/tracker), then you could add a single Apache container which acts as a reverse proxy to each of the 3 Lucee containers.

The additional service for your docker compose file will look something like this;

```
  apache:
    image: httpd
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - /your/path/to/projectx/apache/httpd.conf:/usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf
```

Your Apache configuration can go into a `httpd.conf` which is added to the service via a volume.

Comment: Just for my understanding, when setting it up like this, are we running four different docker containers at the same time? I will give it a try now and let you know how it is going. Thanks so far.

Comment: One remark I have to make is that I do need to add mappings to the Lucee image which are setup in the Lucee administrator and need to be available. So I have will try to amend the Lucee image and commit those new changes to it. Before I used to get Exit 0 messages after amending the image. Let's see what happens now

Comment: That's right, you'll be running 3 Lucee containers and 1 Apache container. I'll amend the above docker compose file with an example of how to add a volume which will let you customise each `lucee-web.xml.cfm` file.

Comment: thanks. I am going on a holiday now for a couple of weeks so I wont be able to try it out just yet